# jqplot horizontal bars issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm trying to set up a horizontal bar graph using jqplot as follows:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('graph', [gData], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: gTicks
        }
    }
});
```

This code works fine with vertical bars, like:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('graph', [gData], {

    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: gTicks
        }
    }
});
```

But when I go to make it horizontal, suddenly the bars no longer line up with the ticks. For example, for some ticks, there may be two or more overlapping bars. And for some, there may be none at all. Finally, there is an additional 'undefined' tick that seems to have tons of bars overlapping.

gData and gTicks are both javascript arrays.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: The undefined category is actually my own creation, but the problem remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work for you is that, what I assume, you are not changing the data accordingly when changing your graph's orientation to horizontal. Therefore, assuming that this is the problem, the chart's data would have to be in the following form, [as in the example at `jqPlot`'s webpage](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php):

```
   [[[2,1], [4,2], [6,3], [3,4]],
    [[5,1], [1,2], [3,3], [4,4]],
    [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]]
```

---

You could also use a value array notation (below), as oppose to the above (array of points) to express a series:

```
  [[200, 600, 700, 1000],
   [460, -210, 690, 820],
   [-260, -440, 320, 200]]
```

This notation would allow you to change the orientation of the chart without worrying about the data format, as presented in the examples below, where data stay the same only appropriate graph's parameters change:

- [Vertical bar chart.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/2mCjW/18/)
- [Horizontal bar chart.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/2mCjW/16/)